# Equivalent of window.screenTop in firefox and chrome

Tags: javascript, window, screen, position

I have a requirement where i need to get the "window.screenTop". But this works just in IE.
I found an equivalent for firefox -  "window.mozInnerScreenY".
Is there something similar for chrome? Or can i get the same result using some other methods?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_screenleft.asp

seems it's cross browser

Comment: I can confirm `scrollTop` is available on Chrome, but it has odd behaviour (it is `-8` when maximized but `0` when the tab is inactive).